# Retrieving data from native query and conversion

Tags: java, jpa, jpql, nativequery

I have following query

```
@Override
public List<PlayerDetails> testPlayerQuerry() {
    return copyPlayersToDetails(em.createNativeQuery("select player_name from player p\n"
            + "join Player_Game pg on p.player_id = pg.fk_player_id\n"
            + "join Game g on pg.fk_game_id = g.game_id\n"
            + "where g.game_id = 2").getResultList());
}
```

which as far as I am aware it return list of String? due to the error I am getting

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to entities.Player
>       at utils.SessionFacade.copyPlayersToDetails(SessionFacade.java:105)

the class which throws the error it is working fine with queries which returns player String for example return * from players

```
private List<PlayerDetails> copyPlayersToDetails(List< Player> players) {
    List<PlayerDetails> list = new ArrayList<PlayerDetails>();
    Iterator i = players.iterator();
    while (i.hasNext()) {
        Player player = (Player) i.next();
        PlayerDetails details = new PlayerDetails(player.getPlayerId(),
                player.getPlayerName(), player.getPlayerRating());
        list.add(details);
    }
    return list;
}
```

How I have to convert this method or how (if possible) I can get those values stored in this String list in to JSF page so I can retrieve the query results?

Comment: [Constructor expressions](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/JPQL#Constructors), [Tuple queries](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Criteria#Tuple_Queries), or `List<Object[]>` can be used, when a query returns a list of tuples i.e. a list of not fully qualified entities as the given query does i.e. when a list of selected fields is needed. (The given SQL query can be reconstructed by using JPQL or criteria. There is no need to fire a native query in this case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `copyPlayersToDetails()` method expects a list of `Player` entities, not a list of `String`. This is why you get a `ClassCastException` here:

```
Player player = (Player) i.next();
```

Because `i.next()` returns a `String`. The reason why your Java compiler didn't complain is because [`Query.getResultList()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#getResultList--) (unfortunately) returns a raw type list.

You should change your native query to this:

```
@Override
public List<PlayerDetails> testPlayerQuerry() {
    return copyPlayersToDetails(em.createNativeQuery("select p.* from player p\n"
            + "join Player_Game pg on p.player_id = pg.fk_player_id\n"
            + "join Game g on pg.fk_game_id = g.game_id\n"
            + "where g.game_id = 2", Player.class).getResultList());
}
```

#### Further criticism

- You should (probably) use a bind variable
- You don't need to join the `Game` table

Write this instead:

```
@Override
public List<PlayerDetails> testPlayerQuerry() {
    return copyPlayersToDetails(em.createNativeQuery("select p.* from player p\n"
          + "join Player_Game pg on p.player_id = pg.fk_player_id\n"
          + "where pg.fk_game_id = :1", Player.class).setParameter(1, 2).getResultList());
}
```

Comment: this works perfectly! I would like to also know how to retrieve data from query which have data form other entities for example like gameScore which is stored in Player_Game table? I am thinking I need method which will do that for me or I need to create PlayerGame and Game objects to retrieve those details??

Comment: @DummyGummy: Feel free to ask a new question. This will get tricky to talk about in the comments...

Comment: I need to wait 90 minutest before posting next question

Comment: @DummyGummy: Alright. That gives you time to phrase it really really well :-)